# TSQL: Conditional WHERE based on param value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, case-when

I have a `WHERE` clause part that needs to swap values depending on a param. What I've written is giving me:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified on a context where a
>   condition is expected.

Also, there is another param that affects the `Order By` as well, but I think that's ok.

Here is the query:

```
WHERE   ( ISNULL(C.QtyCancel, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped, 0) + ISNULL(OI.QtyAssigned, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[ID], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[NG], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[SS], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[ZO], 0) > 0
        )
        --this is the problem line that errors
        --AND CASE WHEN @IsAdmin <> 1 THEN 'AND TD.TempDate = ''01/01/1901''' END 
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)
        WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @Sort <> '' THEN @Sort
              ELSE '[Date]'
         END --<--will this work as well?...
```

Comment: All those ISNULLs in there are really just slowing things down. There is no need to check for NULL and set it to 0 only to exclude it if it isn't > 0. NULL > 0. You could simplify this and make it SARGable by removing all those.

Comment: except for this one.. `OR ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped, 0) + ISNULL(OI.QtyAssigned, 0) > 0`.. you should probably leave this one alone.. or just check them individually since if either one is greater than zero then combined they should also be.. unless you have negative numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE   ( C.QtyCancel > 0
          OR PR.QtyPrinted > 0
          OR ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped, 0) + ISNULL(OI.QtyAssigned, 0) > 0
          OR NP.[ID] > 0
          OR NP.[NG] > 0
          OR NP.[SS] > 0
          OR NP.[ZO] > 0
        )
        AND (@IsAdmin = 1 OR TD.TempDate = '01/01/1901')
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)
        WITH ROLLUP
-- no this will not work.
--ORDER BY CASE WHEN @Sort <> '' THEN @Sort
              --ELSE '[Date]'
         --END --<--will this work as well?...
```

in your order by, you can check the value and then pick the field you want to order by in a Case statement but you can't order by the variable..

```
ORDER BY CASE @Sort WHEN 'QtyCancel' THEN C.QtyCancel
                    WHEN 'QtyPrinted' THEN PR.QtyPrinted
                    ELSE [Date]
               END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is corrected query:

```
WHERE   ( ISNULL(C.QtyCancel, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(PR.QtyPrinted, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(SH.QtyShipped, 0) + ISNULL(OI.QtyAssigned, 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[ID], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[NG], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[SS], 0) > 0
          OR ISNULL(NP.[ZO], 0) > 0
        )
        /*here is what you are trying to achieve*/
        AND (@IsAdmin <> 1 AND TD.TempDate = '01/01/1901' OR @IsAdmin = 1)
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), TD.TempDate, 101)
        WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @Sort <> '' THEN @Sort
              ELSE '[Date]'
         END
```

Comment: Your WHERE correction helped. But the answer below was more complete.